# Continuity argument

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $A(t)$, $t\in I$ a continuous non negative function such that

$$ A(t)\leq CA(t)^2+C\epsilon^2, $$

where $C$ is a fixed positve constant. Show that $A(t)\leq \epsilon$ for all $t\in I$.

I tried to show this, but I just got that $0\leq A(t)\leq \frac{1}{2C} $.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a valid statement at all. First, the continuity seems completely irrelevant—the inequality is just about individual values of $A$, not about nearby values. Second, it seems that both $C$ and $\epsilon$ are fixed, and so counterexamples are easy to construct: if $C=\frac1\epsilon$, then $A(t) = 2\epsilon$ satisfies the inequality with room to spare.

Comment: I'd reformulate the exercise as follows: suppose that $\varepsilon$ is small enough, say $\varepsilon < 1/(2C)$, and that $A(t_0) = 0$ for some $t_0$. Show that $A(t)< \varepsilon$ in $I$.